# Lagstash Timestamp dateparseerror

Tags: logstash

I'm hoping someone could help me with this. I'm trying to get some logs setup properly but I can't seem to get the Timestamp to parse correctly. These are some examples of how my timestamp looks in the log files

```
7:00:01 PM Sunday, October 14, 2018 ||
11:27:13 PM Wednesday, October 24, 2018 ||
12:00:00 AM Tuesday, October 16, 2018 ||
```

I've tried different variations of 
h:mm:ss a EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy or h:mm:ss a EEEE, MMMM d, yyyy

```
date{
        match => [ "log_timestamp", "h:mm:ss a EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy", "hh:mm:ss a EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy", "MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss a"]

        target => "@timestamp"
}
```

I keep getting a dateparseerror though. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked if the `log_timestamp` does not contains any extra characters (including space or line breaks) after the year (or before the time)?

Comment: If the "||" are literal, you'd want to make sure they're not in the field before you try to parse it.  I tested "7:00:01 PM Sunday, October 14, 2018" against "h:mm:ss a EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy" and it works.